# AnyObject & Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'CGFloat'

Tags: ios, swift, cgfloat, anyobject

I have two example functions. Both do exactly the same thing. The difference lies in the **type** of the variable "objectName".

**The first works**. I am specific and set the type to UILabel. Obviously I can only use it with UILabel type objects and recreating the function for each type is just ugly.

```
func _setUILabelTop(objectName: UILabel, location: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat) {
    let originalBottom = objectName.frame.origin.y + objectName.frame.size.height
    objectName.frame.origin.y = location + offset
    objectName.frame.size.height = originalBottom - objectName.frame.origin.y
}
```

**The second doesn't work**. AnyObject is used and XCode gives me an error on lines 2 & 3 of the function. It highlights the text **objectName.frame** with the error: Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'CGFloat'

```
func _setObjectTop(objectName: AnyObject, location: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat) {
    let originalBottom = objectName.frame.origin.y + objectName.frame.size.height
    objectName.frame.origin.y = location + offset
    objectName.frame.size.height = originalBottom - objectName.frame.origin.y
}
```

**My questions:**

1. Is there an object type that allows for UILabel, UIButton, MKMapView
2. Is there a better way of specifying Top, Bottom, Left OR Right
   properties individually, without having to calculate widths?

Please be gentle, I've only been using XCode & Swift for a couple of days and this is also my first StackOverflow post. =)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to set the top position for any object, since not all objects have this property - take for example a `NSString`. However you can get the behavior you need by using `UIView` instead of `AnyObject`, as almost (if not) all `UIKit` controls derive from this class.

```
func _setTop(forView view: UIView, location: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat) {
    let originalBottom = view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height
    view.frame.origin.y = location + offset
    view.frame.size.height = originalBottom - view.frame.origin.y
}
```

Regarding the calculations, you can optimize the `originalBottom` computation:

```
let originalBottom = view.frame.maxY
```